# Complex multivariate derivative

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential

Suppose one is given

$f:\mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$

$f(z_0, z_1) = (z_0z_1, \ 2z_0z_1)$

How would one find a total differential of such function?
My best guess is

$ df = \ (\frac{\partial(z_0z_1)}{\partial{z_0}}, \ \frac{\partial(2z_0z_1)}{\partial{z_0}})dz_0 + (\frac{\partial(2z_0z_1)}{\partial{z_1}}, \ \frac{\partial(2z_0z_1)}{\partial{z_1}})dz_1$

However, my understanding is limited and I'm not sure if it is correct. If somebody could confirm/deny that this is correct or provide more information, it would be great!